# Is it possible to un-babelify (un-transform) a single page JavaScript app built with Babel?

Tags: javascript, babeljs

I have a single page app that was built with Babel es6. I have the babelified source code but no longer the original code or source map. It was permanently deleted and I have no way to get it back. I need to rebuild the app and would like to try to un-transform the Babelified version as much as possible. Is there a way to do this? Are there possibly scripts to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Without source maps, not really. The best you can do is to use e.g. [Prettier](https://prettier.io) to make the code more readable, but it's really difficult to tell how much will you be able to get out of it. If there was minification involved (and I assume there was), then comments, function and variable names etc. are irreversibly lost and these are by far the most valuable parts of the code.